# Pear Mail - Recipient address rejected - Error

Tags: php, pear

I am running into the following error using Pear Mail:

```
Notice: Error in sending mail: Failed to add recipient: user@domain.com [SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: 550, response: 5.1.1 : Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table)] in /PEAR/PEAR.php on line 873
```

The email is not sent. Other email addresses such as Gmail and Yahoo are working OK. It only errors for specific email clients, as far as I am aware.

I am using the following script to send the queued mail:

```
require_once "Mail/Queue.php";

$db_options['type']        = 'mdb2';
$db_options['dsn']         = 'mysql://username:password@localhost/db';
$db_options['mail_table']  = 'mailqueue';
$mail_options['driver']    = 'smtp';
$mail_options['host']      = 'hostAddress';
$mail_options['port']      = 25;
$mail_options['localhost'] = 'localhost'; //optional Mail_smtp parameter
$mail_options['auth']      = false;
$mail_options['username']  = 'user@domain.com';
$mail_options['password']  = 'password'; 

$max_amount_mails = 100;
$mail_queue =& new Mail_Queue($db_options, $mail_options);
$mail_queue->sendMailsInQueue($max_amount_mails);
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this error would be caused for specific addresses?

I am running PHP5.2/Apache2(CentOS 5.5)/Pear Mail 1.2.0/Pear Mail Queue 1.2.6/

Thank you

Comment: FYI, you do not need to assign new objects by reference using `=&`.  This was only needed in PHP 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My goodness, that error message has more padding than error!  Let's split it out a bit.

```
Notice: 
Error in sending mail: 
Failed to add recipient: user@domain.com 
[SMTP: 
Invalid response code received from server 
(code: 550, 
response: 5.1.1 : 
Recipient address rejected: 
User unknown in virtual mailbox table)]
```

That last line is the only one we care about.

The SMTP server looked up the address you were using and is complaining that the user could not be located.  In other words **the address is bogus** and is being rejected.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The address is legitimate as it is my address. What can be done about it?

Comment: Is the SMTP server you are connecting to the same SMTP server that normally accepts mail for that address?  If not, it's possible that the SMTP server is configured to *believe* that it handles mail for that domain (thus the failed mailbox lookup), when in reality it should forward it along to the correct server.  You will need to ask the sysadmin to inspect the configuration of the server... or if you are the sysadmin, good luck.  :)

Comment: Yes, it is the same SMTP server I am connecting to that accepts mail for the email address in question. Is this the cause of the conflict?

Comment: If that's the case, then something is going wrong at the SMTP server level that is causing it to identify the email address as invalid.

Comment: Right. I have found the issue. The domain of the erroring address was located on the localhost but the SMTP server I was trying to send to was located elsewhere. Thank you for your help in identifying the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow that recipient's email is being treated as local mail (e.g. `domain.com` points at your local server, and the username doesn't exist on your machine. Do a DNS lookup on that recipient's domain and see what their MX settings are:

```
$ host -t mx domain.com
domain.com mail is handled by 10 someserver.domain.com
$ host someserver.domain.com
someserver.domain.com has address x.x.x.x
```

Possibly the MX host is a "gag" domain, such as `localhost`, or where the MX server has an IP of 127.0.0.1, which fools spammers into spamming themselves.

Comment: Ah right. The email addresses in question are on the local server. Is there any way around this error?

Comment: Not really - it's an invalid email address, so either use a real address, or set up some fake accounts to accept these emails.